# Why mapping is not working using Entity Framework in visual studio 2015 professional

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I have created a context of Entity Framework like below:
  using System;

```
 using System.Data.Entity;
 using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

 namespace UniversityApp.Models
 {
   public class ProfDb : DbContext
      {

        public DbSet<Professor> Professors { get; set; }
         public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

         }
     }
```

I am using VS 2015 Professional. Then I go to View=>Server Explorer=> Add Connection=> Microsoft Sql Server => In Data Source I choose (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB , and when I go to select a database name I do not find UniversityApp.Models.ProfDb as an option. 
I have also created a new object of ProfDb in one of my controller but still not working. Should anyone tell me why mapping is not working in my application and what I should do?

Comment: Take a look at [Entity Framework Code First to a New Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: @Ivan Stoev I have seen that, the problem is that DbContext is not loading my DbSets in tables

Comment: Please don't [repeat questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41525663/861716). Make them more clear instead. You already got some tips.

Comment: Along with the Code First look at migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
Go to Web config, search for

```
 <entity framework>
```

Add this

```
<contexts>
 <context type="UniversityApp.Models.ProfDb , UniversityApp">
  <databaseInitializer type="Your SEED , UniversityApp" />
</context>
```